# Does requests_cache automatically update cache on update of info?

Tags: python, caching, python-requests

I have a very unreliable API that I request using Python. I have been thinking about using [requests_cache](https://github.com/reclosedev/requests-cache) and setting `expire_after` to be 999999999999 like I have seen other people do.
The only problem is, I do not know if when the API works again, that if the data is updated. If requests_cache will automatically auto-update and delete the old entry.

I have tried reading the docs but I cannot really see this anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`requests_cache` will *not* update until the `expire_after` time has passed. In that case it  will not detect that your API is back to a working state.

I note that the project has since added an option that I implemented in the past; you can now set the `old_data_on_error` option when configuring the cache; see the [`CachedSession` documentation](http://requests-cache.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#requests_cache.core.CachedSession):

> **old_data_on_error** – If `True` it will return expired cached response if update fails.

It would reuse existing cache data in case a backend update fails, rather than delete that data.

In the past, I created my own `requests_cache` session setup (plus small patch) that would reuse cached values beyond `expire_after` if the backend gave a 500 error or timed out (using short timeouts) to deal with a problematic API layer, rather than rely on `expire_after`:

```
import logging

from datetime import (
    datetime,
    timedelta
)
from requests.exceptions import (
    ConnectionError,
    Timeout,
)
from requests_cache.core import (
    dispatch_hook,
    CachedSession,
)

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# Stop logging from complaining if no logging has been configured.
log.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())


class FallbackCachedSession(CachedSession):
    """Cached session that'll reuse expired cache data on timeouts

    This allows survival in case the backend is down, living of stale
    data until it comes back.

    """

    def send(self, request, **kwargs):
        # this *bypasses* CachedSession.send; we want to call the method
        # CachedSession.send() would have delegated to!
        session_send = super(CachedSession, self).send
        if (self._is_cache_disabled or
                request.method not in self._cache_allowable_methods):
            response = session_send(request, **kwargs)
            response.from_cache = False
            return response

        cache_key = self.cache.create_key(request)

        def send_request_and_cache_response(stale=None):
            try:
                response = session_send(request, **kwargs)
            except (Timeout, ConnectionError):
                if stale is None:
                    raise
                log.warning('No response received, reusing stale response for '
                            '%s', request.url)
                return stale

            if stale is not None and response.status_code == 500:
                log.warning('Response gave 500 error, reusing stale response '
                            'for %s', request.url)
                return stale

            if response.status_code in self._cache_allowable_codes:
                self.cache.save_response(cache_key, response)
            response.from_cache = False
            return response

        response, timestamp = self.cache.get_response_and_time(cache_key)
        if response is None:
            return send_request_and_cache_response()

        if self._cache_expire_after is not None:
            is_expired = datetime.utcnow() - timestamp > self._cache_expire_after
            if is_expired:
                self.cache.delete(cache_key)
                # try and get a fresh response, but if that fails reuse the
                # stale one
                return send_request_and_cache_response(stale=response)

        # dispatch hook here, because we've removed it before pickling
        response.from_cache = True
        response = dispatch_hook('response', request.hooks, response, **kwargs)
        return response


def basecache_delete(self, key):
    # We don't really delete; we instead set the timestamp to
    # datetime.min. This way we can re-use stale values if the backend
    # fails
    try:
        if key not in self.responses:
            key = self.keys_map[key]
        self.responses[key] = self.responses[key][0], datetime.min
    except KeyError:
        return

from requests_cache.backends.base import BaseCache
BaseCache.delete = basecache_delete
```

The above subclass of `CachedSession` bypasses the [original `send()` method](https://github.com/reclosedev/requests-cache/blob/master/requests_cache/core.py#L83-L121) to instead go directly to the original `requests.Session.send()` method, to return existing cached value even if the timeout has passed but the backend has failed. Deletion is disabled in favour of setting the timeout value to 0, so we can still reuse that old value if a new request fails.

Use the `FallbackCachedSession` instead of a regular `CachedSession` object.

If you wanted to use `requests_cache.install_cache()`, make sure to pass in `FallbackCachedSession` to that function in the `session_factory` keyword argument:

```
import requests_cache

requests_cache.install_cache(
    'cache_name', backend='some_backend', expire_after=180,
    session_factory=FallbackCachedSession)
```

My approach is a little more comprehensive than what `requests_cache` implemented some time after I hacked together the above; my version will fall back to a stale response even if you explicitly marked it as deleted before.

Comment: This _looks_ like what I need! So I just use it like a `requests_cache.install_cache('cache', backend='sqlite', expire_after=180)` (Do I change the `expire_after`?)

Comment: @TheOnlyOneAround: `requests_cache.install_cache()` patches up `requests` to use the normal `CachedSession`; this doesn't do that. Just a sec and I'll whip up a version that would.

Comment: @TheOnlyOneAround: added how you'd pass in the new cached session version.

Comment: @TheOnlyOneAround: I noticed that the project has since added their own stale-data reuse option; I've updated my answer to reflect this (it wasn't available when I wrote the above approach). Both approaches have merit and both work, but mine is a little more aggressive in keeping stale data available for reuse.

Comment: Hrm, this does not seem to work if I include a timeout, can you fix this? Sorry for the late response.

Comment: @TheOnlyOneAround: define *does not seem to work*. How are you including the timeout?

Comment: @TheOnlyOneAround: I conducted a few tests with `requests.get('http://httpbin.org/delay/3', timeout=4)` and varying the timeout, and the cache will serve me the stale response when the timeout is set to less than 3 (the configured delay for `httpbin.org`).

Comment: @TheOnlyOneAround: note that the response is considered stale still! Next time it'll still try to get a fresh response, and will have to time out again before falling back to the stale cache value.

Comment: I am actually including this into a mini library I am creating for the unreliable API. I have the timeout defined and am using this (the default val for `t` is 3) `json.loads(requests.get(url, headers = { 'User-Agent': 'application/json' }, timeout = t).text)`

Comment: I choose to load it as JSON because the response is JSON.

Comment: @TheOnlyOneAround: `requests` supports JSON responses natively; use `requests.get(url, headers={'Accept': 'application/json'}, timeout=t).json()` (so call `.json()` on the response object). Your choice of User-Agent header makes little sense; you probably wanted to use the `Accept` header instead. You are using the `timeout` parameter correctly; what exactly is the problem there?

Comment: Oooh I see, it timed out. I have no data available for this query, I need to add it to the except line.

Comment: Also for some reason, it does not find JSON with using that, I had to resort to the old way. Must be a problem on the API's side.

Comment: It gives me a ReadTimeout exception (`requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout`)

Comment: It does not seem to work, this api may not respond during the 3 seconds, if it does not I would like to kill it. adding `requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout` to the `except (Timeout, ConnectionError):` line does not seem to help and just leaves an error, can you please help?

Comment: @TheOnlyOneAround: `ReadTimeout` is a subclass of `Timeout`; the exception line as I wrote it will already handle it. But if there was no *previously successful response* the cache cannot return that old stale response either.

Comment: @TheOnlyOneAround: If you need to set the User-Agent, set it to something sensible. It won't have to be `application/json`, that's not really a usable User-Agent identifier. The API is probably filtering on specific user agents, perhaps they don't like you using the default `python-requests` user-agent string, which could indicate they are trying to prevent scripted uses of the API?

Comment: Ah ok, this is starting to become too long. Last question - so if there is no response it will just return an error? Thanks.

Comment: @TheOnlyOneAround: it'll return the last successful response, or an error if there was never such a cached response.

Comment: Sorry, when I use it now it gives me `No handlers could be found for logger "pypixel_cache"` (The name of the script). I tried the basic `logging.basicConfig()` but that makes more problems the way I am using the script, have any ideas?

Comment: @TheOnlyOneAround: I added a null handler for you, see https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#library-config

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like that:

```
class UnreliableAPIClient:
  def __init__(self):
    self.some_api_method_cached = {} # we will store results here

  def some_api_method(self, param1, param2)
    params_hash = "{0}-{1}".format(param1, param2) # need to identify input
    try:
      result = do_call_some_api_method_with_fail_probability(param1, param2)
      self.some_api_method_cached[params_hash] = result # save result
    except:
      result = self.some_api_method_cached[params_hash] # resort to cached result
      if result is None:
        raise # reraise exception if nothing cached
    return result
```

Of course you can make simple decorator with that, up to you - http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808